# Animate a polygon

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to animate a GL_POLYGON. The circle gets drawn correctly and even the animator seems to be working fine. I just see a blank screen when the animation is running. Previously, I had tried animating a GL_TRIANGLE and it seemed to work without a hitch.

```
    private void drawCircle() {
        while(angle <= 360.0) {
            s = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
            c = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
            gl.glColor3d(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            gl.glVertex3d(c * radius, s * radius, 0.0);
            angle += delangle;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {
        rangle = (rangle + rdelangle) % 360;

        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glPointSize(5f);
        gl.glPolygonMode(GL.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_FILL);

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotated(rangle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
        drawCircle();
        gl.glEnd();

        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }
```

Animator:

```
FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(canvas, 5);
animator.start();
```

Comment: Do you understand that you're trying to draw different primitives by using the same vertices? http://csclab.murraystate.edu/bob.pilgrim/515/lectures_04_files/gl_vertices_options.jpg

Comment: Is this all the code? Where is ___delangle___ declared and what value is it set to?

Comment: Fixed the error. I had forgotten to reset `angle`.